# How to show code and syntax highlighting with line numbers on a website?

Tags: javascript

I would like to show programming languages on a website without any of it being initialized and whatnot. [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is apparently a good starting point to use, however I do not know how I would be able to add the line numbers at the side. The styles I will be about to figure out though.

Best Regards,
Tim

**Update:**

Although I have ticked for a best answer, I have discovered Google does in fact offer exactly what I'm looking for!

**Update**

I change my mind, the version I have chosen for the best answer offers loads of programming languages and Google does not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pastebin, Gist?

http://pastebin.com
http://gist.github.con

Both do what you want.

Or, if you're looking to do it on your server

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with PateBin, however I would like to show the same on my own website and not a third-party website so to speak. I would like to release a bundle including some on-screen code.